# How keras oov_token=True works

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

By default how does keras impute out-of-vocabulary token when *oov_token=True*.

According to keras official documentation it tells that *if given, it will be added to word_index and used to replace out-of-vocabulary words during text_to_sequence calls*.
However, no much details when not explicitly specified but *oov_token=True*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you are referring to the `oov_token` of the `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer`, you should take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/1.1.2/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L314) to understand what is happening under the hood. In the `text_to_sequence` method, you see that the index of the `oov_token` is added on two occasions for `oov_token=True`:

1. When a word in a sequence is not found in `word_index`, which is the dictionary of each word in your vocabulary mapped to a unique integer value.
2. When you set the maximum number of words to keep using `num_words` and `i` being the index of a certain word, is equals to or above `num_words`.

Here is the related code:

```
vect = []
for w in seq:
    i = self.word_index.get(w)
    if i is not None:
        if num_words and i >= num_words:
            if oov_token_index is not None:
                vect.append(oov_token_index)
        else:
            vect.append(i)
    elif self.oov_token is not None:
        vect.append(oov_token_index)
yield vect
```

Also, [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/1.1.2/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L237) you see that the `oov_token` always gets the index 1 if it was set to `True`.